# How to specify ControlID attribute of Ajax Update Panel for dynamically created controls

Tags: asp.net, ajax

If a control  such as checkboxlist is created dynamically.
like this

```
CheckBoxList CbxList = new CheckBoxList();

CbxList.ID = "Cbx";
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    CbxList.Items.Add(new ListItem(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Name"]
        .ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()));
}
ph.Controls.Add(CbxList);
```

If on the selectedIndexChange event of the created checkboxlist(cbx) if i am updating an ajax update panel how should i specify the ControlID Attribute. I did try **Cbx** in my case but it says no controls and off course that control  is not created yet. So how to handle this issue

Comment: You'd really be doing yourself, and any future maintaining programmers a service by using variable names that follow standard name conventions, and splitting that `Add()` line up into distinct steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of needing a control ID is the triggers collection; if that is the case, why not put the checkboxlist within the updatepanel, and use an updatemode="always" on the panel itself?

Comment: Nice idea you have given. I will give it a try but the thing is the structure of the page is very complex for that i have to put the whole page inside in the update panel. so for that reason i asked in the forum that can the 
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="??????" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> be changed dynamically

Comment: You may be able to change the ID; I'm not sure if the UpdatePanel retains it via state, so you'd have to change it on every postback.  And it can only be changed from the server...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want each checkbox to have an ID?
In that case, don't use a CheckBoxList, but use place holder instead, and add CheckBox controls to it.
However, I think the way you do it, they should get IDs such as 'Cbx_0','Cbx_1',...